# Category id error while training detectron2 model on custom dataset

Tags: object-detection, detectron

My custom dataset which I am trying to train through detectron2 consists of 193 classes.

```
    cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NUM_CLASSES = 193
```

This is how I have set the number of classes in the model configurations, but every time I run my model I am getting an error "AssertionError: Got an invalid category_id=194 for a dataset of 193 classes"

I have tried setting it as 194 as well.

How do i resolve this issue?